# Split a given number so that their sum adds to another given number

Tags: python, python-2.x, time-limit-exceeded, memory-optimization

> **Task**
>
> You are given a string S containing only decimal digits ('0' through
>   '9') and a number N. Your task is to insert an arbitrary number
>   (including zero) of plus signs '+' into S in order to form a valid
>   expression whose value is equal to N.
>
> **Input**
>
> - The first line of the input contains a single integer T denoting the number of test cases. The description of T test cases follows.
> - The first and only line of each test case contains a string S, followed by a space and an integer N.
>
> **Output**
>
> For each test case, print a single line containing one string — your
>   solution, i.e. the expression obtained after inserting some plus signs
>   into S. If there are multiple solutions, you may output any one. It is
>   guaranteed that at least one solution exists.

My code is not very optimized but gives the correct answer. Help me find an optimized version.

```
import itertools
case=input("")

for i in range(case):   

    text,text2=str(raw_input("")).split()

    text=list(text)
    text1=""
    l=[]
    def break_down(text):
        words = text.split()
        ns = range(1, len(words)) # n = 1..(n-1)
        for n in ns: # split into 2, 3, 4, ..., n parts.
            for idxs in itertools.combinations(ns, n):
                    yield [' '.join(words[i:j]) for i, j in zip((0,) + idxs, idxs + (None,))]

    for i in text:
        #to add whitespace in between so that split() functions separates it correctly 
        text1=text1+i
        text1=text1+" " 

    for x in break_down(text1):
        #this part calls the generator and sums every iteration
        sum=0
        answer=""

        for i in range(len(x)):
            #removing the whitespaces that were added before 
            x[i]=x[i].replace(" ","")
        #converts string to int so that it actually adds number not concatenates them
        x=[int(i) for i in x]


        for i in x:
            #calculating sum
            sum+=i
        if sum==int(text2):

            l=x 

        #if the sum is equal to given number then it prints it out in the asked manner
        for i in l:
            i=str(i)                
            answer+=i
            answer+="+"
    if int(text1.replace(" ",""))==int(text2):
        print int(text1.replace(" ",""))
    else:
        print answer[:len(answer)-1]
```

**Example Input**

```
4
15112 28
120012 33
123 123
15489001 10549
```

**Example Output**

```
15+11+2
1+20+012
123
1548+9001
```

Comment: I'm assuming Python 2.7.x here. If you're using an older version, please clarify.

Answer (score 7):

## Python 2

Python 2 is end-of-life, and Python 3 has a lot of advantages now:

- f-strings
- unicode support
- ...

More info [here](https://pythonclock.org/), [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Oiw23yfqQy8) and on many other places.

If you need python 2.7, try to make your code compatible with [both](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/pyporting.html).

## Split it into functions

You do that to a limited extent with `break_down`, but you can do it in a lot more places:

- parsing the input
- breaking the input into parts
- calculating the sum of the parts
- output

  ```
  from __future__ import print_function
  ```

## Parsing the input

you do `input("")` a lot. If you skip the `""`, you can test your input parsing with something like

```
input_str = '''4
15112 28
120012 33
123 123
15489001 10549'''
input = iter(input_str.split('\n')).__next__
```

In the parsing of the input, you iterate over the string, insert a space between characters and then split on the space, while all you need to do is `list(text)`.

So I would go for:

```
def parse_input():
    cases = int(input())
    for _ in range(cases):
        question, answer = input().split()
        yield question, answer

list(parse_input())
```

> ```
> [('15112', '28'), ('120012', '33'), ('123', '123'), ('15489001', '10549')]
> ```

## Splitting the input

This is what your `break_down` does. But you format its answer as a `str` with spaces between the numbers. Why not just yield the ints immediately with `int(''.join(words[i:j]))` instead of `' '.join(words[i:j])`

instead of `words` for the collection of digits, I would use `digits` as name. Same with `ns` and `n`, I don't find their purpose clear by their name, but I can't find a good, clear name instantly either.

For python 2 and 3 portability, you will need to do `list(range(...))`, because you iterate over `ns` twice

And your solution with `zip((0,) + idxs, idxs + (None,))` is also well found, but not clear what exactly it does. The same idea can be made more clear using the `pairwise` itertools recipe.

```
def pairwise(iterable):
    '''
    s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ...
    https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes
    '''
    a, b = itertools.tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)

def break_down(text):
    digits = list(text)
    ns = list(range(1, len(digits))) # n = 1..(n-1)
    for n in ns: # split into 2, 3, 4, ..., n parts.
        for idxs in itertools.combinations(ns, n):
            idxs = (0, *idxs, None)
            yield tuple(int(''.join(digits[i:j])) for i, j in pairwise(idxs))
```

## Calculating the sum

instead of

```
    x=[int(i) for i in x]


    for i in x:
        #calculating sum
        sum+=i
```

you can use the builtin `sum` (if you don't overwrite the name with a variable like here) `total = sum(map(int, x)` does the same as these original 3 lines.

But since we already got `int`s from the previous part instead of strings, just `sum` will do:

```
def check_sum(question, target):
    for parts in breakdown(question):
        if sum(parts) == target:
            yield parts
```

formatting the answer can also be more efficient and clear than manually putting `'+'` between all parts.

```
def format_answer(answer):
    return '+'.join(map(str, answer))
```

## Putting it together

```
def solve_query(query):
    question, target = query
    target = int(target)
    answer = next(find_sums(question, target))
    return format_answer(answer)
```

and then, behind a main guard:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    queries = parse_input()
    for query in queries:
        print(solve_query(answer))
```